# Ubuntu 18.04: List View for Icons on the Desktop

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus, icons

I have a number of files cluttering my Desktop. I would like to view the files as a list (e.g., "delete" folder on right vs. grid layout of the same folder on the left). I prefer list view because it is much more compact, especially when file names are long. I have tried various gsettings (e.g., using folder manager to draw Desktop and making list view default), but these changes only affect nautilus, rather than icons on the Desktop. How do I get list view on the Desktop itself?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears support for this feature has/is being stripped away by Nautilus.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/gnome-desktop-icons-removed-3-28

Also tried the work-around by using Nemo to manage the desktop.

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-replace-nautilus-with-nemo-file.html

Was not successful in getting Nemo to manage the desktop, perhaps due to the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nemo/+bug/1742193